# Check if many records exists in the same request in CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to migrate data from a SQL database to CRM 2011.
I had run a first pass setting only the required fields and the identifier from the SQL database.
Now I should retrieve the entities and update the values with the lookups.

I am performing insertion and update using bulk operations (ExecuteMultipleRequest).
Is there a similar way to check if a collection of entity is already created, and possibly retrieve their id if that's the case?

The single entity check is really slowing things down.

This is the method I use to check if the record is existin:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if the entity with the specified value on the specified field exists
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entityName">Name of the entity</param>
/// /// <param name="field">Field to be checked</param>
/// <param name="fieldValue">Value to be checked</param>
/// <returns>The GUID of the existing return if it exists, an empty one otherwise</returns>

public Guid CheckIfExisting(string entityName, string field, string fieldValue)
{
    try
    {
        QueryExpression entityQuery = new QueryExpression(entityName);
        entityQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(entityName + "id");
        entityQuery.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
        entityQuery.Criteria.AddCondition(field, ConditionOperator.Equal, fieldValue);

        EntityCollection retrievedEntities = service.RetrieveMultiple(entityQuery);
        if (retrievedEntities.Entities.Count >0 && retrievedEntities.Entities[0].Id != null)
            return retrievedEntities.Entities[0].Id;
        else
            return Guid.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an exception of type" + e.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Error message " + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

    }
    return Guid.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code which you are using to check existing records. We can work on the query to improve the performance time. Also SQL Server Indexes can also help to improve the query time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a number of these types of integration jobs to CRM. There are two main ways of going about this

The easiest way is to use the excellent kingswaysoft SSIS component for CRM  http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm .This is good as it gives you an "upsert" options out of the box that allows you to do this. It does however suffer from the same problem of checking each record with CRM.

The second more complicated but better performing way is to use SSIS to compare things for you. The basic premise is to get two list, one for your source and one from your destination and join them using a full outer join. Using a conditional split your logic is this

- If its in source but not in destination, insert
- If its in destination but not in source, delete
- If its in both then update

This works well for large quantities of data when performance is a factor.

Comment: I really love your second option! I think I'm gonna use it in my next project, but right now that would require a huge change in the code, that I don't have the time to implement. My idea now is to allow all the values on the retrieve query (like chunks joined by or conditions), add the retrieved entities to a dictionary with the field as the key and check the existence directly in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok then in the meantime you can use the IN condition of a query expression and pass a list of IDs. That would only be one hit on CRM. In the response you would then loop through your passed list of IDs and see which ones came back

Comment: Kevin, we use your second option and I tell you it is really fast. One thing I would add is don't use the Sort from SSIS rather sort the source and destination component as it is lot faster.